# Trying to post info to database via wordpress but just showing up as '0'

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme and i'm trying to add an additional field into the themes backend (it's for a gallery slider that has a description and caption text box, I'm trying to add a "quote" box).

As I'm a novice with databases, I've found the relevant files and copied all references to "description" and changed the word to "quote". I also added a "Quote" column into my table.

Everything appears to work fine, however when I type in text to the input field in the backend and click save, it changes the text to "0"

Does anyone know why this might be, what have I done wrong?
[image]

I think this is the code that posts to the DB....like I say though I'm a noob with DB's

```
add_action('wp_ajax_list_slider_items', 'list_slider_items');
function list_slider_items()
{
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT IMAGEID, TYPE, CONTENT, THUMB, CAPTION, DESCRIPTION, QUOTE, WIDTH, HEIGHT FROM {$wpdb->prefix}backgrounds WHERE GALLERYID='".$_POST['GALLERYID']."' ORDER BY SLIDERORDER");
$i=0;
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo getSliderItemImage($row->IMAGEID, $row->TYPE, $row->CONTENT, stripslashes($row->CAPTION), stripslashes($row->DESCRIPTION), stripslashes($row->QUOTE), $row->THUMB, $row->WIDTH, $row->HEIGHT);
    $i++;
}
die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_save_slider_items', 'save_slider_items');
function save_slider_items()
{
global $wpdb;
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['imageID']); $i++)
{
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'backgrounds', array('CAPTION'=>$_POST['CAPTION'][$i], 'DESCRIPTION'=>$_POST['DESCRIPTION'][$i], 'QUOTE'=>$_POST['QUOTE'][$i], 'SLIDERORDER'=>($i+1)), array('IMAGEID'=>$_POST['imageID'][$i]), array('%s', '%s', '%d'), array('%d')); 
}
die();
}
```

And this looks liek the code that created the table:

```
function create_backgrounds_table(){
global $wpdb;
$prf = $wpdb->prefix;
$create_query = <<<EOT
CREATE TABLE `{$prf}backgrounds` (
  `IMAGEID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `GALLERYID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SLIDERORDER` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `EXT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CAPTION` text,
  `DESCRIPTION` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `QUOTE` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `CONTENT` text,
  `THUMB` text,
  `WIDTH` int(11) default NULL,
  `HEIGHT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`IMAGEID`),
  KEY `GALLERYID` (`GALLERYID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
EOT;
$create = $wpdb->get_results($create_query);
}
```

Comment: Show your db structure. Specially column type of "Quote".

Comment: you may have wrong column type as @Rikesh told and may have set the NULL value

Comment: Added screenshot of the table

Comment: That seems okay. Can you check the code which post the value and just echo the query if possible. so that we can see how the values and send to DB

Comment: Posted what I think is the code that posts to the DB

Comment: can you use 'QUOTE'=>esc_html($_POST['QUOTE'][$i]) to achieve this?

Comment: Added that in, didn't work though sadly. Can't understand why it won't post to the DB